# Serve PHP using the Webstorm server

Tags: javascript, php, webstorm

I'm developing a website in Webstorm.

I have a small requirement for some server side functionality and am doing it in PHP rather than Node at this stage.  But, Webstorm's internal web server doesn't appear to serve PHP files.

A simple AJAX request to a PHP file like the one below doesn't return a file list, it returns the contents of the file

```
<?php
    $files = scandir("./pdfs");
    foreach($files as $file) {
        echo $file;
        echo "\n";
    };
?>
```

If I serve the site from Apache it works fine.

Is there some configuration I'm not setting in Webstorm or can't it do what I'm trying to do?

If it can't, can I integrate Apache into Webstorm?

Comment: PHP script runs fine in the Webstorm terminal which I have configured using CYGwin and Apache2

Comment: Webstorm is an IDE, Apache is a web server. What do you want? Anything unclear?

Comment: I want to be able to test a project in Webstorm.  It will serve JS/HTML etc but doesn't seem to serve PHP.  I would have thought I could develop a whole web project including server and client side, like I would if I was developing with an Apache localhost

Comment: Why Webstorm then? You can still access your website in browser, if your files are hosted by your Apache. Just edit the files directly in Apache web root folder.

Comment: Have been using Sublime for ages, just switched to Webstorm for Node development, it's a nice IDE.  Didn't think a little bit of PHP would be that hard though

Comment: I don't think PHP requires an IDE. Notepad++ is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by following the guide at http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/create-new-project-add-local-server.html

This explains how to use an existing server (in my case Apache2) as the server for Webstorm instead of the built in server.

I also needed to change the URLs in the run/debug configuration to point to my Apache web root

Works fine now.

Comment: That's a broken link these days, but this one works: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/creating-local-server-configuration.html